# Get contact attachments using API

Tags: hubspot-api

I am able to retrieve attachments from contact object but I can't view that attachment because its by default hidden true. How I can retrieve those files without uploading in file manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files are attached as note engagements on the contact and would be returned in this [API](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/engagements/get_associated_engagements) and then [get the file metadata](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/files/get_files_file_id) from there. One thing to note though is that if a file was uploaded outside of the file manager in HubSpot, i.e. attached directly on the record, then it will show as hidden:true and you can not get the file metadata via API.